# Power series of quantum mechanical eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, calculus

In Griffith's Quantum Mechanics book, when he tackles time-independent perturbation theory, he states that one can write the eigenfunctions of the perturbed system,
$$
H = H^0 + \lambda H',
$$
as a power series in $\lambda$,
$$
\psi_n = \psi_n^0 + \lambda\psi_n^1 + \lambda^2\psi_n^2 + \cdots
$$
I'm trying to understand this intuitively. I am guessing that this is some way of writing the Taylor expansion of $\psi_n$. Then I do indeed understand that summing up all the terms gives us the full eigenfunction to arbitrary precision.

I just can't see how the power series in the book is really a Taylor expansion. Given that this is time-independent, the eigenfunctions should be functions of $x$, and their general Taylor expansion should look like
$$
\psi_n(x) = \psi_n(a) + \psi_n'(a)(x - a) + \frac{\psi_n''(a)}{2!}(x - a)^2 + \cdots.
$$
He writes that $\psi_n^1$ is the first-order correction to the $nth$ eigenfunction, $\psi_n^2$ the second-order, and so on. Can this statement be reconciled with writing the corrections as
$$
\psi_n^m(a) = \frac{1}{m!}\frac{d^m\psi_n(x)}{dx^m}\bigg\rvert_{x=a},
$$
such that the Taylor expansion becomes
$$
\psi_n(x) = \psi_n^0(a) + \psi_n^1(a)(x - a) + \psi_n^2(a)(x - a)^2 + \cdots,
$$
or what? I would still need to define something like
$$
x - a \equiv \lambda
$$
to get
$$
\psi_n(x) = \psi_n^0(a) + \lambda\psi_n^1(a) + \lambda^2\psi_n^2(a) + \cdots,
$$
but this forces some dependencies on $\lambda$ that isn't physically motivated, and screws up the relations between $x$, $a$ and $\lambda$ in the equation, so it seems like a stupid thing to do.

Comment: The eigenfunctions(eigenvectors are functions of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perturbed functions are meant to be a Taylor expansions in $\lambda$, not in $x$.
More completely it should be written as:
$$\psi_n(x,\lambda) = \psi_n^0(x) + \lambda\psi_n^1(x) + \lambda^2\psi_n^2(x) + \cdots$$

So the $\psi_n^m(x)$ are the Taylor coefficients around $\lambda=0$.
$$\psi_n^m(x) = \frac{1}{m!}\frac{d^m\psi_n(x,\lambda)}{d\lambda^m}\bigg\rvert_{\lambda=0}$$

Comment: Why more completely? In general, the $\psi$s are just elements of some Hilbert space. You don't have to work on $L^2(\mathbb R)$. For example, one might consider a perturbative expansion on $\mathbb C^2$, when e.g. considering some spin-$1/2$ particle (and neglecting the spatial degrees of freedom).

Comment: @TobiasFünke In general you are correct. But as Griffiths talked about eigen*functions*
I assume he treated it in the $x$-representation, i.e. in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense Thomas Fritsch, but how can we be sure that $\lambda$ should be evaluated in $0$, where $H = H^0$, and not in $1$, where $H = H^0 + H'$?

Comment: The whole point in perturbation theory is that the perturbation is *small*,
i.e. $H' \ll H_0$. Therefore an expansion around $\lambda=0$ is the natural choice.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch with $\lambda = 0$, there is no perturbation?

Comment: @Depenau Yes, sure. But with a small $\lambda$ near zero we have a small perturbation.

Comment: Can I think of it this way; the same way we can obtain $f(x)$ from derivatives of $f(x)$ evaluated at zero, we obtain $\psi(\lambda)$ by piling on corrections, so in that sense we get to know $\psi(1)$ even though we keep evaluating in $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: @Depenau Yes, you can think this way.